# Python equivalent to java.io.File

Tags: java, python

I'm writing script to automate system administration tasks on my Linux system.

This involves compressing, moving, deleting, renaming and searching a lot of files. I learned doing these in Python by looking up examples on Internet and here on Stackoverflow.

The typical approach is to create a command string and pass it to the OS to have it executed.

```
print Popen("cat /home/kshitiz/myfile", stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
```

The directory paths are handled as strings.

Now consider following example:

We have a program that asks user for a dir and a file and creates a path. If a user enters `/home/kshitiz` and `myfile` the path becomes `/home/kshitizmyfile`. In Python I must do jugglery with strings to deal with this. In Java I can simply do: `new File(parentDir, filename)`

Since Python is supposed to be better at OS administration it surprises me that it doesn't have object oriented abstractions over the file system.

**What are the other approaches in Python to deal with the file system?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`os.path` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html):

```
path = os.path.join(parentDir, filename)
```

Comment: Wow that was easy. :)

Comment: Are there modules that would let me deal with running processes and allow killing and searching?

Comment: There is [`psutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil), or just use the `os` and `subprocess` modules directly.